# How can I pass values from columns of a parent dataframe to operate on a nested dataframe two levels below?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

My tibble `shocks_small` is structured with several regular columns of parameter values including `mu1`, and several list columns prefixed with `v1_v2_T`. Each observation of these list columns is another tibble, with a regular column indicating the simulation number and another list column `v1_v2` containing a tibble of random variables (`v1` and `v2`).

Is is possible to pass the parameter values from the parent tibble down two levels of depth to a function operating on the random variables tibble? The goal would be to iterate through each row of the parent table, then again through each simulation.

This code works, because it does not require any values from `shocks_small`:

```
shocks_small %>%
  modify_at(vars(starts_with("v1_v2_T")), \(z)
            z %>% map(\(x)
                      x %>%
                        mutate(v1_v2 = map(v1_v2, \(y) 
                                           y %>% mutate(e1 = lag(v1, 1))))))
```

This code, however, throws an error, presumably because the most deeply nested `map`-`mutate` cannot seem to find the `mu1` value.

```
shocks_small %>%
  modify_at(vars(starts_with("v1_v2_T")), \(z)
            z %>% map(\(x)
                      x %>%
                        mutate(v1_v2 = map(v1_v2, \(y) 
                                           y %>% mutate(e1 = mu1 + lag(v1, 1))))))

Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: v1_v2_T12.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `v1_v2 = map(v1_v2, function(y) y %>% mutate(e1 = mu1 + lag(v1, 1)))`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `e1 = mu1 + lag(v1, 1)`.
Caused by error:
! object 'mu1' not found
Backtrace:
  1. shocks_small %>% ...
 35. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., e1 = mu1 + lag(v1, 1))
 36. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
 38. dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
 39. mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 40. dplyr (local) eval()
```

Is there a way to access back up to `shocks_small` from the innermost `map()` or to pass the `mu1` value along each iteration? Appreciate any suggestions.

**Update:**
Here is code to reproduce a simplified dataset to be compatible with the code I've provided:

```
intermediate_tbl1 <- map_dfr(1:5, ~ map_dfc(1:2, ~runif(5)) %>% 
      set_names(c("v1", "v2")) %>% 
      mutate(repl = .x) %>% 
      relocate(repl, .before = everything())) %>% 
      nest(v1_v2 = c(v1, v2))

intermediate_tbl2 <- map_dfr(1:5, ~ map_dfc(1:2, ~runif(10)) %>% 
          set_names(c("v1", "v2")) %>% 
          mutate(repl = .x) %>% 
          relocate(repl, .before = everything())) %>% 
  nest(v1_v2 = c(v1, v2))

parameter <- tibble(mu1 = c(1, 2))

shocks_small <- parameter %>% mutate(
  v1_v2_T = list(intermediate_tbl1, intermediate_tbl2)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demo using `mutate(across(..), ..)`, I think the use of `modify_at` is "hiding" some of the surrounding context. It is roughly the same procedure. However, the key here is that we need exactly one `mu1` per nested-`map`, and even when we can use `mu1`, it'll be length-2 instead of the group-wise that we need. For this, I'll pass it down via `pmap` instead of `map`.

```r
out <- shocks_small %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("v1_v2_T"),
           \(z) pmap(list(z, mu1), \(x, mu)
                     mutate(x, v1_v2 =
                                 map(v1_v2, \(y) mutate(y, e1 = mu + lag(v1, 1))))) )
  )
out$v1_v2_T[[1]]$v1_v2[[1]]
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#       v1     v2    e1
#    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.664  0.163  NA   
# 2 0.216  0.637   1.66
# 3 0.0754 0.0446  1.22
# 4 0.572  0.838   1.08
# 5 0.208  0.564   1.57
```

Once we get past the first `map`-level with `pmap`, it appears our `mu` (length-1) is visible to the lower levels.